# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found (ZULU 11)

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework, liferay-dxp

We updated the our environment Liferay DXP 7.2 to 7.4, In 7.2 All my soap services are working fine, in tomcat-9.0.33 and we have below property file "jaxws.properties" "javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl".
Now we are running in Liferay 7.4 (tomcat-9.0.73), All soap services are not working, we are getting "javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found" exception. I changed jaxws.properties as "javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl". but still I am getting same Error.

In dependeny I have added
implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-rt', version: '2.3.2'
implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-ri', version: '2.3.2'

same error only I am getting, if anyone knows please Hepl me.

Note: Java versions are not changed  we are using ZULU 11.

Thanks.

In Soap UI all Services are working. we didnt changed the Java Vesion. We are using Zulu 11